# How to check if cursor is between specified tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, tags, cursor

There are some `formatted` text inside the `textarea` and a cursor is in some place. I need to check if the cursor is between some specific tags.

Example:
**foo`|`bar**.

```
isBetween(['b', 'strong']); // should return true in above case
```

I have `function` that returns `position` of the `cursor` inside `textarea` (is has some `IE` issues, but satisfies me for now). So, all I need is that `isBetween()` `function`.

Thanks for any help!

**Update**:

```
<p>qwer<b>ty|ui</b>op</p>
isBetween(['p']); // should also return true, because the cursor in not only between 'b', it is between 'p' too
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose the space between the tags with a `span` tag.
Then, in jQuery, use the [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) function.

Example:

```
<b>TAG1</b>
<span id="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
<strong>TAG2</strong>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#spacer").mouseover(function(){
        //Do stuff
    });
</script>
```

The span has to have something in it, so throw an `&nbsp;` in there as a space.

Live fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/PrruT/

**UPDATE:**

I'm not going to do the whole function for you, but I'll tell you that you could set it up like this:

```
/* I'm assuming you can figure out how to get the cursor position on your own, represented by var cursor */

function isBetween(selectorOne, selectorTwo){
    var left = $(selectorOne).position().left; //Left position of the object
    var right = $(selectorTwo).position().left + $(selectorTwo).width(); //Right XY position of the object
    if (cursor > left && cursor < right)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Also, as a side note, know that <b> and <strong> are deprecated, and that you should be using `css` to style your objects (`<span style='font-weight: bold;'>Hello</span>`).